# Git push is resetting permissions of hooks?

Tags: git

I'm fairly new to git but I'm trying to set up git to deploy my website to my server.

I have created a bare repo called `etw.git` on my server and created `post-receive` within `hooks` which has the following:

```
#!/bin/sh git --work-tree=/home/username/www --git-dir=/home/username/www/etw.git checkout -f
```

I've created a local repo called `etw.git` and initialized it.

I then did `git remote add live ssh://username@mydomain.com:18765/home/username/www/etw.git`

My problem is that when I do `git push live master` it will succeed but the updated files will only display on my website if, before doing `git push live master`, I use `chmod -R +x hooks` to modify the permissions of my `/home/username/www/etw.git/hooks` folder.

Here is what `hooks` looks like before using the chmod:
[image]

And once I do `chmod -R +x hooks` it looks like:
[image]

Git push only will work AFTER I do `chmod -R +x hooks`.

But after I `git push live master`, the permissions get reset (back to first image) and I have to execute `chmod -R +x hooks` again before doing another push.

Also when pushing to server it pushes ALL 4000+ objects instead of only the modified ones. That makes it take a long time.

Lastly, after pushing to server, my `post-receive` loses the `#` and it simply becomes:

```
!/bin/sh git --work-tree=/home/username/www --git-dir=/home/username/www/etw.git checkout -f
```

Comment: I've never messed around with hooks, but aren't they just shell scripts anyway?  As long as /bin/sh is executable, shell scripts themselves don't need to be.

Comment: @Powerlord: Git won't *run* a hook if it does not have the `x` bit(s) set.

Comment: I am willing to bet that your post-receive hook removes and replaces your Git directory. Check the contents of your repository, i.e., what it will write to the work-tree; and check whether some of your files / directories, such as ~/public_html, are symbolic links.

Comment: @torek Yes you're right, thanks. I don't know how but it was replacing my git directory every push. I completely reset my local repo and that fixed it.